# Geocoding address as soon as table in PostGIS is updated

Tags: python, sql, gis, postgis

I am trying to use Python to geocode a list of addresses I have stored in a table in PostGIS. I would like to set things up so that every time the table is updated, and a new address is added, it would automatically be geocoded (and then plotted on a map). The only way I could think to do so was to use plpythonu to create a geocoding function, and then some combination of update and trigger to get what I wanted. However, plpythonu is acting really weird (I might ask about that here later, but for now I am looking for alternative solutions rather than figuring out plpythonu) .

I can't think of another way to set things up so an entry is geocoded as soon as it is entered into the database? Can someone give me some ideas on where to start looking?

Answer (score 2):

You sort-of answered your question. Use a [database trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) which modifies a row when it is inserted or updated. First, make a simple address geocoding wrapper function using a `geopy` Python 3 module:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geocode_address(address text)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
if location:
    return 'SRID=4326;POINT(%r %r)' % (location.longitude, location.latitude)
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpython3u VOLATILE COST 1000;
```

Test it out:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geocode_address('175 5th Avenue NYC'));
```

... should return `POINT(-73.9366879 40.814044)`.

Now you can use the function anywhere, including this trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geocode_address_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  NEW.geom := geocode_address(NEW.address);
  RETURN NEW;
END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Then apply the trigger functions to `mytable`, with `address` and `geom` fields.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_geocode_address
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE geocode_address_trigger();
```

Comment: The problem is that google geocoder does not work in plpgsql. You can create your own geocoder,but I really don't want to use the tiger geocoder or nominatim for reasons specific to the project. I tried, like you suggest to work from plpythonu, but plpythonu won't work. My version of plpythonu is compiled against Python 3.2. Pip install geopy (or any other module), or manually installing geopy is not working for reasons I cannot understand (they work fine in 2.7 and 3.4). I guess I was hoping there was an answer other than the common sense/ easy way of doing it that I could not think of.

Comment: Your answer is very good. I actually suggested that he use a trigger on a similar question on gis.stackexchange, but decided the question was firmly in the not enough research/find me a tool/give me teh codez camp.